# How to verify that an object transfer is complete

Tags: java, crc

I want to send a message (a serializable object) from a java instance to another instance over a network. I would like to verify that the whole object has been sent correctly.

I suppose my first step is to calculate the checksum of the object. Then I include that checksum in the object OR build a container object for the message and its checksum.

Then my second step should be to verify the checksum against the object on the other side.

My third step would be for the receiver to send a confirmation message saying that the object in question was received and that the checksum has passed (or not). If I receive a failed checksum warning, I try to resend it a few times.

After a little while, if I never received a confirmation, I try to resend it a few times as well.

Questions :

Does my protocol sounds right to verify that an object was transferred correctly ?

I would also like to know how am I supposed to implement this in java ? Do I use the CRC32 class to generate the checksum ?

Bonus question : If I were to compress each message, do I generate the checksum before of after the compression, and how do I compress an object in java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reasonably reliable network with a low error rate, you shouldn't need to add an additional checksum. I would implement your protocol without a checksum first and add if you are sure you need it.

You can compress the data with DeflatorOutputStream, InflatorInputStream.  If the compressed data is corrupted the Object is highly likely to throw an exception when unpacking it. i.e. it is very unlikely to have a subtle error.

However, unless your objects are large, they may not compress very well and could endup being larger with compression.

Answer (score 1):

For compression, I would like to recommend the Apache Zip Utilities:
http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/package-summary.html

If you are compressing then you can skip the checksum.  Compression algorithms are quite sensitive to data damage.  If the object fails to decompress on the other end, then you lost some information during transmission.

Comment: Why Apache zip utilities? The JDK also contains classes which work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your steps, with one addition (this is what I do, over ObjectIO streams) -
[1] Read the incoming stuff as Object, find its class with "instanceof". If it is not the expected class, time to debug what is coming in.

In some other situations, I also send out Strings that contain info about the contents of the object to arrive next. Parse this string, read the object, typecast it, make sure it has what the info in the String said, and write out the confirmation :)